# How to convert UnityEngine.UI.Button to string

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

i wanna trigger event if word length is equal into current word length set event. and i cant set it because my code is error and have response like( Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.UI.Button' to 'string'

My code :

```
public Button cek;    
public static string currentword;
public static int wordleng;
    
    if (Input.GetButtonDown(cek))
    {
     wordleng = currentword.Length;
     Debug.Log("Button Work");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing a [Unity UI Button](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html) and the [Input Get Button Down](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html). The two are very different.

If you want to compare a word when the user clicks a UI button, you will need to assign an [onClick](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) either by adding a listener in code in the `Start()` function or by adding the onClick in the inspector by dragging in an onClick.

Example code could look like

```
private void Start()
{
    cek.onClick.AddListener(CompareWords);   
}

private void CompareWords()
{
    wordleng = currentword.Length;
    Debug.Log("Button Work");
}
```

If you want to compare this word after the user clicks a certain key or mouse input, you will need to use a [KeyCode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) for a key or either `Fire0` or `Fire1` (These are project dependent but are generally defaulted to those values. To find out what yours are, Go to **Edit > Project Settings > Input Manage**).

Example code could look like

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        wordleng = currentword.Length;
        Debug.Log("Button Work");
    }
}
```

After re-reading your post, I believe you want to check if your target word is of a certain length. You are currently using the `=` operator which is an assignment operator. To determine if two values are equal, you would want to use a comparison operator `==`. And your code would change slightly. If I were to use the first example again it would look like

```
private void Start()
{
    cek.onClick.AddListener(CompareWords);   
}

private void CompareWords()
{
    if(wordleng == currentword.Length)
    {
        Debug.Log("Word is the same length");
    }
}
```